# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

HI I'm running selenium with spring and cglib.

I get this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder

but i cant find the related package any where!!
anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The package is included in ApacheHttpComponents [httpcore](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/).

If working with Maven, simply add the following as a dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```